# Как можно двигать объект по разным осям относительно таргета Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мой код который я использовал что бы двигать камеры относительно таргета

```
public Transform target;
public float sensitivity = 3; 
void Update ()
{
    transform.RotateAround(target.position, transform.up, Time.deltaTime*  sensitivity);
    transform.RotateAround(target.position, transform.right, Time.deltaTime * sensitivity);
}
```

Comment: А просто написать `transform.RotateAround(target.position, transform.position, Time.deltaTime*  sensitivity);` ?

Comment: Всё равно он движется по одной оси, в одном направлении